# Is there a limit to the amount of GMP you can have at any one time?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

As per the title, is there a cap on GMP (money)? If so, what is the limit?

I am on just over 4 million at the minute and don't really like spending money if I don't need to, but if there is a limit I might just buy random stuff if I start getting close to it.

Comment: There has been no mention of a GMP cap, and I doubt that there is one. At least one that is achievable by a regular user. As I understand it you'll be able to use the GMP when MGO launches in October as well.

Comment: OK, may be a coincidence, but I just landed on exactly 5 million GMP. Seems strange that I have exactly that amount, going to try earning some now and see what happens

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two different limits, offline and online.  When the game was initially released, only the offline gmp/resources were available.  But further patches enabled online modes.

I've maxed out and can't gain anymore GMP (and also can't spend any of it due to research duration/limits).

```
Offline Limit    5,000,000 GMP
Online Limit    25,000,000 GMP
Overall Limit   30,000,000 GMP
```

[image: maxed out]

Answer (score 3):

OK, so it just so happens that I was pretty close to the limit already. The limit appears to be 5,000,000 (5 million) GMP.

I noticed I had exactly that amount and then when I went to accept some GMP as part of a completed combat deployment mission, the following message was displayed:

> Unable to accept all rewards. You have reached your maximum item capacity.

Yes I know it says "item" but after closing that dialog, there are two unclaimed rewards still listed, both of which are GMP.

It seems quite a low limit as I now have 440,000 in rewards waiting to collect. Would be interesting to know if those rewards will expire or if I can keep them there until I need the money. Though I think I will just spend some cash and claim them to be safe

Comment: Chances are good if you've hit the limit, you can probably spend some cash without fear of running dry later. :P

Comment: I generally accumulate up to near the limit, then blow a few million on development projects.